# Python count multiple matching strings on same line in a file

Tags: python

I need to print & count two matching words in same line of a file using python

Example:

```
abc-1(P1)[2cpu 440H 54MB][RI-STD RAMBOO abc-1]: IDLE
abc-2(P1)[2cpu 440H 54MB][RI-STD RAMBOO abc-2]: IDLE
abc-3(P1)[2cpu 440H 54MB][RI-STD RAMBOO abc-3]: RUNNING
abc-4(P1)[2cpu 440H 54MB][RI-STD RAMBOO abc-4]: RUNNING
abc-5(P1)[2cpu 440H 54MB][RI-STD RAMBOO abc-5]: IDLE
abc def ghi
emb abc ref
```

In the above I need to count number of line matching string "abc" & "IDLE" and if the count of both string is more than 2, print "abc" string with full name

As per above example, I want to print "abc-1" "abc-2" abc-5" if count of "abc" and IDLE is above 2.

May I know how to do in python ?

note: I don't want to print "abc" if IDLE is not present in same line

Comment: Too broad - where should we start? Do you know how to open a file?

Comment: @Natasha include some of the code you wrote in your answer. Tell us what went wrong.

Comment: Also, you want count of 'abc' >2 AND count of IDLE > 2 or count of 'abc' + count of IDLE >2 ?

Comment: @timgeb Yes I am aware of open and read a file

Comment: @archer yes, first I need to count matching both "abc" and "IDLE" if its greater than two print corresponding full abc value example "abc-1"

Answer (score 0):

Please try below program to read from file and print the output

```py
with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    list(map(print,[line[:line.find("(")] for line in f if line.count("abc")>0 and line.count("IDLE")>0]))
```

**Output**

```
abc-1
abc-2
abc-5
```

Comment: This will print all "abc" matches in  a file without IDLE, I want to print only "abc-1" if IDLE and "abc" present on same line

Comment: I have updated the program above. please check now.